# Is it possible to group multiple paths to use the same header in Netlify _header config?

Tags: netlify

According to [Netlify docs for custom headers](https://www.netlify.com/docs/headers-and-basic-auth/) I can create a path to use custom headers

```
# use these headers for the /index.html file
/index.html
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
```

However, what I can't seem to figure out is if I can have multiple paths use the same header without having to create a new entry per path

```
/*.js
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public

/*.css
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
```

I've tried the following and none have worked

```
/*.js /*.css
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public

/*.js
/*.css
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public

/*.js, /*.css
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diclaimer:  I work for Netlify.

Our header file format isn't that flexible - you'll need one rule per globbed path (e.g. `/*.css`).  Some folks who have complex needs generate the file programatically:

```
find . -name assets -type d -exec echo "{}/*.css:\n  Header: value" >> public/_headers
```

or something similar to that.

However - be very careful manipulating the cache control settings! We choose them with GREAT care as explained in this article:

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/02/23/better-living-through-caching/

to support atomic rollbacks and deploys.

If you change them, you'll get negligible performance increases at the risk of totally removing the ability to update those files for return visitors.  One assumes you're using cachebusting or asset fingerprinted URL's so that those URL's change each deploy and/or whenever content changes?

Regardless, that's not even the best way to solve that problem.  Our asset optimization does all of that for you already:

- creates an asset-fingerprinted URL for you on one of our CDN's (those assets will load from cloudfront, not your custom domain)
- rewrites the references in your content (css/js/html) to point to those assets
- with year-long caching headers

This IS safe since those URL's are asset-fingerprinted - any change in content changes the URL's.  You activate this near the bottom of your Build & Deploy settings page and it is free at all account levels.

I'd write in to our support team for more guidance.  If you're seeing terrible performance or something you're trying to overcome here - we'd love to help you fix the root cause rather than see you potentially break your site with long-lasting bad effects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As for the cache headers, I wasn't using netlify's asset optimization since I was minifying assets myself during the deploy. But it looks like netlify will do all that for me so I'll try it out and see what happens.

Comment: A message from the Netlify control panel: "Netlify’s built-in asset optimization feature is deprecated and will be at end of service on October 17, 2023".

Comment: good call-out, @ogggre !  From now on you'll have to manually minify and bundle things if you want optimized assets. Frankly - modern tools are better at these days than the old Netlify feature (webpack, for instance), and those tools are also definitely more flexible too!